# How to load jquery files on header in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I want to load my jquery files on header, my all of jquery files loading via Yii2 assets. Any body knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add that line to AppAsset file,

```
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        'yii\web\jQueryAsset' //I means this line
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In AppAsset file add:

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\JqueryAsset'
];
```